# How exactly do "in=angle" and "out=angle" translate to the path in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know what exactly do the parameters `in` and `out` map to the path used.

Specifically, say I draw a path with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [in=30, out=40] (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How could I draw the same path using controls, if possible.

In the manual I only managed to find that using in and out in the to specification translates to using a special path, but I couldn't find  exactly which path and I am not sufficiently versed in TeX to read the sources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The controls may be expressed as points relative to the start and end points, and this may be done in polar form.  The first control has angle of `out` and the second angle of `in`.  Now in the abscence of other options the length of the controls are equal to `0.3915` times the distance between the start and end points.  Thus in your case the distance is `5` and the control length is `1.9675`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] (0,0) to [in=30, out=40] (5,0);
\draw[red,dashed] (0,0) .. controls +(40:1.9675) and +(30:1.9575) .. (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The number `0.3915` may be found in the file `tikztopathslibrary.code.tex`.  The manual states that it is chosen so one gets an approximate quarter circle when the directions are at right angles.  If a different value of `looseness` is specified, this is used to scale this factor.